# dotnet ef database update in Docker container fails with error permissions

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to build a docker image that will run EF Core migrations in my production environment, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to configure access rights so that I run with a user that has minimal rights, but still enough to perform the task. My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine3.7

# Create an app-specific user, to avoid running as root
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S app && \
    adduser -u 1001 -S app -G app
USER app

# Connection string is set when starting the container
ENV ConnectionStrings__MyContext = "<set the ConnectionStrings__MyContext environment variable!>"

# Build the app inside the home dir of the app user
WORKDIR /home/app/db-update
COPY MyApp.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build --configuration Release

# Apply migrations using the SDK
CMD dotnet ef database update
```

But when I try to build an image from this file, the `dotnet restore` command fails with the following error:

```
Step 8/11 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 8df166ad5be0
  Restoring packages for /home/app/db-update/MyApp.csproj...
  Restoring packages for /home/app/db-update/MyApp.csproj...
  Installing System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.0.
  Installing System.Memory 4.5.0.
  ... a lot of packages ...
  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault 2.1.0.
  Generating MSBuild file /home/app/db-update/obj/MyApp.csproj.nuget.g.props.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path '/home/app/db-update/obj' is denied. [/home/app/db-update/MyApp.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Permission denied [/home/app/db-update/MyApp.csproj]
ERROR: Service 'notes-db_migrations' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It doesn't seem to help what working directory I choose (e.g. `/db-update` or `/home/app/db-update`), I get the same permission denied error anyway.

What's the correct way to configure this?